# Gazebo camera timestamp issue

Tags: ros, gazebo, camera, rostime, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I use a gazebo camera like this:

```
<sensor:camera name="camera1_sensor">
  <imageSize>160 160</imageSize>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_camera name="controller-cam1" plugin="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
    <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
    <imageTopicName>/gazebo/cam1</imageTopicName>
    <cameraInfoTopicName>/gazebo/cam1/info</cameraInfoTopicName>
  </controller:gazebo_ros_camera>
</sensor:camera>
```

The timestamps for full second N is actually output as N-1 + 1000000000ns. This leads to weird behavior, for example when using

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(image_message1->header.stamp)
```

in a C++ application, as it produces the string "{N-1}.10" instead of the expected "{N}.00".
I assume that it is probably wrong to blindly use the lexical_cast on every datatype that comes along. And actually this is not a big issue, if you finally realize that it works that way.
But I wonder if this is the correct behavior/usage of ROS::Time? Can I expect other components that output ROS::Time tho behave in the same way and should I do it the same if I ever was to create a ROS::Time object?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11690/gazebo-camera-timestamp-issue/) by [nitschej](https://answers.ros.org/users/992/nitschej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe `ros::Time()` has an `operator<<()`, which should do the correct normalization.

Have you tried that?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nitschej](https://answers.ros.org/users/992/nitschej/) on 2011-10-30**:
Ok, I'll try that. Btw. I wonder, doesn't lexical_cast actually use the ostream operator?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-27**:
It probably should. Either that, or the ros::Time() implementation intended to maintain normalized data as an invariant. We should open a defect ticket.

**Comment by [nitschej](https://answers.ros.org/users/992/nitschej/) on 2011-10-26**:
I didn't know about that operator until now. But I checked it and it does not normalize the output stream.